# Comparar ambos lados de una matriz en java

Tags: java

Estoy intentando hacer un programa que diga si la matriz es igual desde cualquier lado en la que se mire en capas, es decir, en la matriz

```
1 1 1 1 1
1 2 2 2 1
1 2 3 2 1
1 2 2 2 1
1 1 1 1 1
```

tiene una primera capa de unos, luego otra de dos y una ultima de tres. Para ello cojo la triangular inferior y la superior, esta ultima invertida y las comparo y saldría 112123122211111 dos veces, por lo que son iguales.
He probando el comparar ambas matrices o el meter los números de la matriz en un array y luego compararlo pero no me lo compara, ya que en esa matriz tendría que salir que es igual. El código que tengo es:

```
public class matrizigual {

public static void main(String args[]) {

    int[][] matriz = { { 1, 1, 1, 1, 1 }, { 1, 2, 2, 2, 1 },
            { 1, 2, 3, 2, 1 }, { 1, 2, 2, 2, 1 }, { 1, 1, 1, 1, 1 }, };
    imprimirMatriz(matriz);
}

public static void imprimirMatriz(int[][] matriz) {
    int lado = matriz.length;
    int[][] matriz1 = new int[lado][lado];
    int[][] matriz2 = new int[lado][lado];

    for (int i = 0; i < lado; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j <= i; j++) {
            matriz1[i][j] = matriz[i][j];
            System.out.print(matriz1[i][j]);

        }

    }
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println();

    for (int i = lado - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        for (int j = matriz[i].length - 1; j >= i; j--) {

            matriz2[i][j] = matriz[i][j];
            System.out.print(matriz2[i][j]);

        }
    }
    System.out.println();
    if (matriz1 == matriz2) {
        System.out.println("Es igual");

    } else {  
        System.out.println("No es igual");
    }

  }
}
```

Comment: La comparativa matriz1 == matriz2 va a dar siempre false. Debes hacer la comparativa elemento a elemento.

Comment: Ya se que ahí esta el fallo pero no se como solucionarlo. He intentado también con los arrays.

Comment: @Fernando al igual que elemento a elemento la vas imprimiendo, elemento a elemento vas comparando

Comment: Tal como lo tienes ya estas usando arrays. Si lo que necesitas es comparar 2 arrays de igual dimension simplemente tienes que hacer lo siguiente boolean iguales = true; for(int i=0;i<array1.lengh;i++){ for(int j=0;j<array1[i].lenght;i++){if(matriz1[i][j] != matriz2[i][j]){ iguales=false;}}} Ahora ya solo tienes que ver lo que vale iguales, en caso afirmativo son iguales, en caso contrario no lo son.

Comment: Me da un error y no cuando soluciono ese error no me lo hace.

Answer (score 1):

Tienes que utilizar el siguiente comparador para matrices:

```
Arrays.deepEquals(matriz1, matriz2)
```

El comparador `==` resuelve que son objetos diferentes (distintas referencias), puedes probar así:

```
for (int i = 0; i < lado; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j <= i; j++) {
        matriz1[i][j] = matriz[i][j];
        matriz3[i][j] = matriz[i][j];

        System.out.print(matriz1[i][j]);
    }
    System.out.println("");
}
```

... y si comparas las matrices *1*  y *3*  con `==`, el resultado es falso, en cambio, con `Arrays.deepEquals(matriz1, matriz2)` el resultado es positivo.

Comment: Me sigue dando false de esa manera de deepEquals.